# crawling data from site having JSon

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want to crawl data from the web page https://www.balticshipping.com/vessels including ship info from its detail pages such as https://www.balticshipping.com/vessel/imo/9331713 and save this data to CSV tables. While going to the next page I see that the URL didn't change, so I don't know how to get data from all pages at the same time. Is there any specific way to get all this data in one CSV file?
[Next button inspection view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuSaX.png)

```
import requests
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        
        baseurl ='https://www.balticshipping.com/'
        headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
        
        productlinks = []
        response = requests.get('https://www.balticshipping.com/vessels') 
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        productlist =soup.find_all('div', id="search_results")
         #loop to get all href from ul
        for item in productlist:
            for link in item.find_all('a', href = True):
                productlinks.append(baseurl + link['href'])
        print(productlinks)
```

I tried this code to get all links from the current page, but it give me an empty result maybe there is some error in line 'productlist =soup.find_all('div', id="search_results")', because it didnot takes any data by using id instead of class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access that data through the api. But keep in mind, you'll be iterating through about 7700 + pages of data.

The `'year_build'` column is in epoch which represents the seconds since January 1, 1970. So just need to convert that to a timestamp, then from that datetime timestamp, pull out the year.

For the type and countries, we just need to find the associated ids, then can create a dictionary that we then can map the id to the corresponding value. In this case, we get those ids and names from another request, just need to change the parameters in the post form data.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url ='https://www.balticshipping.com/'


# Get Country and Type Ids and create a lookup dictionary 
payload = {
'templates[]': ['modal_validation_errors:0',
              'modal_email_verificate:0',
              'r_vessel_types_multi:0',
              'vessels_list:0',
              'vessels:0'],
r'equest[0][module]': 'top_stat',
'request[0][action]': 'list',
'request[0][id]': '0',
'request[0][data]': '',
'request[0][sort]': '',
'request[0][limit]': '',
'request[0][stamp]': '0',
'dictionary[]': ['countrys:0',
           'vessel_types:0']}
    
jsonData = requests.post(url, data=payload).json()

country_ids = pd.DataFrame(jsonData['data']['dictionary']['countrys']['array'])
country_ids_dict = dict(zip(country_ids['id'],country_ids['name']))
type_ids = pd.DataFrame(jsonData['data']['dictionary']['vessel_types']['array'])
type_ids_dict = dict(zip(type_ids['id'],type_ids['name']))


ships_found = True
page = 0
rows = []
#while ships_found:
for page in range(10):
    payload = {
    'request[0][module]': 'ships',
    'request[0][action]': 'list',
    'request[0][id]': '0',
    'request[0][data][0][name]': 'search_id',
    'request[0][data][0][value]': '0',
    'request[0][data][1][name]': 'name',
    'request[0][data][1][value]': '',
    'request[0][data][2][name]': 'imo',
    'request[0][data][2][value]': '',
    'request[0][data][3][name]': 'page',
    'request[0][data][3][value]': f'{page}',
    'request[0][sort]': '',
    'request[0][limit]': '27',
    'request[0][stamp]': '0',
    'request[1][module]': 'top_stat',
    'request[1][action]': 'list',
    'request[1][id]': '0',
    'request[1][data]': '',
    'request[1][sort]': '',
    'request[1][limit]': '',
    'request[1][stamp]': '0'}
    
    jsonData = requests.post(url, data=payload).json()
    
    if len(jsonData['data']['request'][0]['ships']) == 0:
        ships_found = False
        print('End of Pages.')
        
    else:
       for each in jsonData['data']['request'][0]['ships']:
           row = each['data']
           rows.append(row)
        
       page += 1
       print(page)
       
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)

# Convert the epoch to timestamp and pull out the year
df = df.rename(columns={'year_build':'epoch_year_build'})
df['year_build'] = pd.to_datetime(df['epoch_year_build'], unit='s').dt.year


# Use the lookup dictionaries to map the ids to corresponding names
df['country_name'] = df['flag_id'].map(country_ids_dict).fillna(df['flag_id'])
df['type_ship'] = df['type'].map(type_ids_dict).fillna(df['type'])


# SPLIT THE COLUMN
formerNames = df['former_names']

formerNames_merge = pd.DataFrame()
for idx, row in formerNames.iteritems():
    try:
        temp = pd.json_normalize(row)
        temp.columns = ['formerNames_' + col for col in temp.columns]
        temp.index = [idx] * len(temp)
    except:
        temp = pd.DataFrame()
    
    
    formerNames_merge = formerNames_merge.append(temp)


df = pd.merge(df, formerNames_merge, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

**Output:**

Here I'm just showing the columns you talked about needing to convert, but otherwise all the data that was previously there, is still all there for you.

```
print(df[['id','name','type','type_ship','flag_id','country_name','epoch_year_build','year_build']].head(5).to_string())
       id         name  type         type_ship  flag_id      country_name epoch_year_build  year_build
0  166434  RED DIAMOND     9      Bulk carrier       99           Liberia       1293840000      2011.0
1  190081        LEDRA     9      Bulk carrier       44            Cyprus       1356998400      2013.0
2  246691        MESTA    26  Crude oil tanker      111  Marshall Islands       1609459200      2021.0
3  246690     CHASELKA    26  Crude oil tanker      197         Hong Kong       1483228800      2017.0
4  172285        EVANS     9      Bulk carrier      111  Marshall Islands       1230768000      2009.0
```

Comment: yeah, this one takes a long time. Can we set the page range to this one, like the previous one?

Comment: yup. See edit. Just change the number to indicate how many pages to go through

Comment: Thanks, it's work and you did a lot. I am searching on year_build to change its format now its format is like 1293840000, 1356998400 because it is really important for me.

Comment: Also, another important piece of information is missing 'Flag',  from JSON, which country name and type of ship, JSON has just flag id and type id. is there any solution for it?

Comment: I’ll take a look at it when I get a chance. But won’t be until tomorrow.

Comment: ok, I will wait. Thanks

Comment: @Anwar, alright mate. Got you the country, type, and convert the epoch to get the year for ya

Comment: yeah, it works. Thank you so much...

Comment: I tried different ranges like 50, 100 it works but when I put range numbers like 500,1000, or more so the result gets stucks on different pages like sometimes 60, 90, and stop there. I change my internet connection but still have that problem.

Comment: does the code just hang/stall out? or do you get an error?

Comment: just hang for a long time. I tried different times and it hung on different pages.

Comment: Hello There! from this Csv I found one column 'former_names' has different data can we spilt it into different columns?

Comment: @Anwar. Yes that can be split. There's a few ways to do it. You could create multiple columns like `'former_name01'`, `'former_name02'`, etc. This will keep a single row for each instance, but will  leave some columns with many nulls, since the length of the `former_names` list are not equal. The other other option is to normalize it into each row to represent each time there was former name. This will keep the width of the table the same, but will greatly expand the length of the table. But will have an instance for each time the ship name changed.

Comment: @Anwar, I went with the later. There is possibly a better/more efficient way to do this, but I'll leave that up to you to work through if needed.

Comment: Lastly, it's better practice to post a new question, as opposed to just continuing in the comments with additional questions/requests. It's also important that you do/show some effort otherwise you can be viewed as a [help vampire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire). For example, simple google search could have led you to [here](https://pretagteam.com/question/how-to-split-a-pandas-column-with-a-list-of-dicts-into-separate-columns-for-each-key) for the solution (or any of the first 10 or so results  is a search of `"split a column with a list of dicts"`

Comment: @chitwon  Thanks for your precious time. yeah, I got it, there are some repetitions in id, IMO, and others but I hope it will be managed using PostgreSQL (Relational Database).  and you are the one who answer all the questions I had, yeah I am a very weak student but I am learning it. Thanks again

Comment: hello! I tried the same techniques you used for flag_id to change it to a specific country name but it didn't work for "formerNames_flag_id". I focus on the same dictionary  : country_ids = pd.DataFrame(jsonData['data']['dictionary']['countrys']['array'])
country_ids_dict = dict(zip(country_ids['id'],country_ids['name'])) for former flag id.

Comment: @Anwar, I am no longer answering your questions to this post. You posted this question 2.5 months ago, and you received a solution 2.5 months ago. 4 days ago I politely advised you to not continue posting follow up questions to this post. If you have a question that's beyond the scope of the original question/post , post it as a new one. Lastly, there's no such thing as a "weak" student, but there is such a thing as a "dependant" student.

Comment: ok. problem solved thanks

Answer (score 0):

@chitown88 solution works but from what i've seen API provides incomplete data, so my solution is to query ship details by `IMO number`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

baseurl ='https://www.balticshipping.com'

# Sample iteration from first page to page 10
for pagenum in range(10):
    payload = {
        'request[0][module]': 'ships',
        'request[0][action]': 'list',
        'request[0][id]': 0,
        'request[0][data][0][name]': 'search_id',
        'request[0][data][0][value]': 0,
        'request[0][data][1][name]': 'name',
        'request[0][data][1][value]': '',
        'request[0][data][2][name]': 'imo',
        'request[0][data][2][value]': '',
        'request[0][data][3][name]': 'page',
        'request[0][data][3][value]': pagenum,
        'request[0][sort]': '',
        'request[0][limit]': 9,
        'request[0][stamp]': 0,
        'request[1][module]': 'top_stat',
        'request[1][action]': 'list',
        'request[1][id]': 0,
        'request[1][data]': '',
        'request[1][sort]': '',
        'request[1][limit]': '',
        'request[1][stamp]': 0
    }

    response = requests.post(baseurl, data=payload)
    try:
        jsondata = response.json()
    except requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError:
        print("Error occured while decoding JSON response.")

    ships = jsondata['data']['request'][0]['ships']
    for ship in ships:
        ship_imo = ship['data']['imo']
        print(ship_imo)
        # Now query ship details by its IMO number
        # just replace number in this example url: https://www.balticshipping.com/vessel/imo/9331713
        # resp = requests.get('{baseurl}/vessel/imo/{ship_imo}'.format(baseurl=baseurl, ship_imo=ship_imo))
```

Comment: {'id': 166434, 'imo': 9331713, 'mmsi': 636014524, 'name': 'RED DIAMOND', 'type': 9, 'year_build': '1293840000' here 'year_build': they get the wrong information I think?

Comment: `year_build` is correct. It's just in [`timestamp`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp) so you can convert it to readable date in python. You can check it here for example: https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

Comment: ok, I will try. Thanks